# Extract a Zip Archive using PHP

Tags: php, zip

what i'm trying to do is to basically extract the contents of Zip archives on my server.Here is some code:

```
$entry="test.zip";

    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    if ($zip->open($entry,ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
    {
        $zip->extractTo('unpacked');
        $zip->close();

     }else 
     {
        echo ‘failed’;

     }
```

the directory "unpacked" is writeable for everyone and all the used methods of the ZipArchive Class return true. However nothing is being extracted. Does anyone happen to have an idea what  could cause this behaviour? Any hint will be highly appreciated...Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your web server's error log say?  Do you get extra errors displayed if you turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: i don't get errors, when i echo out $zip all i get is "true"...its weird

Comment: And what do you see when you `var_dump($zip);` ?

Comment: oh-- when i use var_dump i get num_files = 0...that would explain why i get back true but nothing is extracted...however my archive definitely contains files...

Comment: And have you tried running this from the command line?  Does the process running this PHP script (perhaps your web server) have read access to the zip file?  Lots of basic things to check...  And you're sure that NOTHING is reporting an error?

Comment: thanks for your reply!yes, i tried running it from the command line, i triple checked all the permissions, still - no error, but no result...i now use shell_exec(unzip...) as a workaround, however i would still like to know why the previous (standard) solution doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is in-house, and you can safely make the assumption that you won't move this code from Linux to Windows (or vice versa), you also have the option to execute local system commands, which may help solve your problem.

```
<?php

echo `unzip myarchive.zip`; 
echo `tar -xzf myotherarchive.tar.gz`;

?>
```

When developing internal-use and/or maintenance scripts, I used to opt for straight-up system calls, as it was more in-line with the commands sysadmins were used to using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will definitely try that. However i'm still wondering WHY my solution doesn't work...

Comment: Can this be done if the file is hosted remotely? Like for example, wordpress, so instead of downloading locally and upload, just place the above code on your host server and extract the wordpress archive directly from wordpress.org into it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 5.2.0 or later can you check zlib extension first http://www.zlib.net/

You also check PECL extensions, In order to access ZipArchive, you can also try zip_open, zip_read just for checking.

Answer (score 1):

In case of failure you should echo out `$zip` as it contains the error.
Furthermore I'd guess that you may not have the needed permissions for test.zip

Answer (score 1):

If your zip archive is big, sometimes you cannot extract all files during the maximum allowed execution time of your server.

The only solution, if you cannot change the maximum_execution_time in your php.ini, is to use a javascript to extract one file after the other. On the first javascript request you take the number of files in the archive

```
$nbr_of_files = $zip->numFiles;
```

And after you extract one file after another using the id number in the zip archive for each file

```
$zip->extractTo('unpacked', array($zip->getNameIndex($file_nbr)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing the ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE flag from the ZipArchive open method. (The flag may not be functioning as expected and may be the root of the issue if you have followed the advice in the other answers.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too. The solution:

```
$zip->extractTo(public_path() .'/restoreDb/extracted/');
```

add the `public_path()` helper function.